# Apache 2.4 segmentation fault when accessing certain localhost Symfony 2 PHP files

Tags: php, symfony, apache2

I've run into a really odd problem.  I have a new Linux Mint 17 install on my local machines, with Apache 2 and PHP 5.6 obtained through [Ondrej Sury's PPA](https://launchpad.net/~ondrej/+archive/ubuntu/php5-5.6).  I have cloned a Symfony 2 project to my system from GitHub.

After setting up the project (installing vendors through composer, giving read/write permissions to the cache and logs, etc.), I ran `localhost/diva/web/config.php` in the browser to ensure that my system was ready to go.  It ran fine and gave me the green light.  When attempting to look at the home page at `localhost/diva/web/app_dev.php/` it gave me a 'The connection was reset' error.  Very odd.  `app.php/` produced the same.

Looking at the server logs, I see a series of segmentation faults along the lines of:

> [Thu Oct 30 18:15:10.291111 2014] [core:notice] [pid 1557] AH00052: child pid 2974 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)

I *have* moved the document root, from what was (I believe... it's been a while) `/var/public/html` to `/home/kevin/www` for my own ease of use.  I did that with the following modifications:

/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
    # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
    # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
    # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
    # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
    # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
    # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
    #ServerName www.example.com

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /home/kevin/www

    # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
    # error, crit, alert, emerg.
    # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
    # modules, e.g.
    #LogLevel info ssl:warn

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
    # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
    # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
    # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
    # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
    #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
</VirtualHost>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

and in /etc/apache2/apache2.conf:

```
<Directory /home/kevin/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

/etc/hosts simply has:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.1.1   Shevat

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts

::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

I'm a newbie when it comes to setting up Apache.  I've successfully moved my document root in older versions of both Apache and Mint, but this is the first time something like this has happened.  I can't tell if I've messed something up with my configuration changes.

And, just to be perfectly clear, other PHP files work fine when accessing them through the browser.  I can access my own test files at various nested directory depths within `~/www/*`, and even Symfony's `config.php` works as expected.  It's only when I attempt to access those two specific Symfony files - `app_dev.php` and `app.php` that the problem occurs.

What's even more strange is that the problem persists across two computers.  It's happening on both my desktop and my Surface Pro 3.  They use the same essential VirtualBox environment, but have been installed separately.  They're not cloned environments.

I'm not sure where to go at this point.

Comment: `DocumentRoot /home/kevin/www` should point to `path/to/project/web`. This path `path/to/fresh/install/web/app_dev.php/` is not for the browser, just `http://localhost/`

Comment: Well, the paths are really like `~/www/project1/web`, `~/www/project2/web` and so on.

Comment: First of all, check that your apache is running. Because browser does not an answer from it and switches to `www.localhost.com` as can be seen from the attached image.

Comment: Apache is running.  Like I said several times, `~/www/project1/web/config.php` runs just fine, as well as other PHP files located in `~/www`.  It's only when I try accessing `~/www/project1/web/app.php` or `~/www/project1/web/app_dev.php` with the browser that the problem occurs

Comment: It looks like it may be a server issue after all, given the segfaults I'm seeing in the log.  Really weird.  I'm using, IIRC, Apache 2.14

Comment: `2.14`?? may be 2.4.1? Probably corrupted version of php, which kills server. Try to reinstall it.

Comment: Did your Symfony install include Vendors?

Comment: Yes, vendors are installed.  I ran composer update before attempting to access it.  And, yes @Cheery, you're right, it's 2.4.1.  Too many version numbers floating around :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Solved by rolling back to the versions of Apache and PHP that are available to Linux Mint by default (Apache 2.4.7 and PHP 5.4.8).

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
php -S localhost:8000
```

as a server, for me it works fine

Comment: I get the following: $ php -S localhost:8000 
PHP 5.6.2-1+deb.sury.org~trusty+2 Development Server started at Thu Oct 30 19:24:24 2014
Listening on http://localhost:8000
Document root is /etc/apache2
Press Ctrl-C to quit.

Comment: @KevinM1 he meant to use php's internal http server instead of apache.

Comment: @Cheery I'm afraid I'm not sure how to do that.  I'm going to downgrade both Apache and PHP.  I only need PHP 5.3.8 for Symfony, and any version of Apache 2 should work.